# Golang thread not executing every time

Tags: multithreading, go

So, I am testing Golang. I understand fmt.Println is not thread safe. So, I was trying out sync.Mutex. The following is the program:

```
func threder(mux *Mutex, i int) {
    mux.Lock()
    fmt.Println("I am thread: ", i)
    mux.Unlock()
    return
}

func main() {
    m := &Mutex{}
    for i := 0; i < 300; i++ {
        go threder(m, i)
    }
}
```

I am expecting 300 lines of output. But, I am getting 80-90 lines. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your `main` returns, all other threads are killed. As your `main` returns right after starting all threads, some of them don't get to print. You can use [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to wait for all threads to stop:

```
func main() {
    m := &sync.Mutex{}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 300; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            threder(m, i)
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

About your comment: If you do not pass the `sync.Mutex` as a pointer, but the value, to the function the `sync.Mutex` will be copied and each copy will operate independently of each other. Therefore there will be no synchronization between threads, as they all use their own, independent `sync.Mutex`. Also, you must not copy a `sync.Mutex` after the first use, as stated in the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex). This would not happen in your case, as you copy before using the `sync.Mutex`, but be aware of it.

Comment: I have one more question. What happens if I don't pass a pointer to the mutex i.e. instead of &Mutex{}, if I just do Mutex{}?